# .htaccess for exclude URL and remove www. and switch to https

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to write a Redirect/Rewrite Rule with .htaccess with these needs:

- Remove www from URL
- Switch http to https
- Remove a trailing Slash
- Exclude one URL from https

Here i am a little bit stuck with my knowlege:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/api/do/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

Here are some Example URLs (i hope this makes it clear):

```
http://www.test.de --> https://test.de
http://www.test.de/ --> https://test.de
https://www.test.de/ --> https://test.de
http://test.de/api/do/ --> http://test.de/api/do/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is this what you need

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   # CONFIGURE HTTPS
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://YOUR-SITE.COM$1 [R,L]
```

Replace https://YOUR-SITE.COM to your corrent domain

Comment: Thanks, but http : //www.test.de/ ist not going to https: //test.de, also the slash at the End sould be removed (and /api/do/ should be excluded from https) - sorry

Comment: to make it more clear could you show how your url is and how would you expect ?

Comment: Thanks, i added some examples in the question

Comment: test now again , replace  `https://YOUR-SITE.COM to your corrent domain`

Comment: Thanks, but still not working as (http://test.de/api/do/) --> (http://test.de/api/do/) still switches to https. Also thre is a . showing up after http://

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some time, i got this solution. Maybe it could be done with less lines. but it seems to work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# REMOVE WWW & FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{https} off 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/do(/*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://igst.org/$1 [R,L]


# REMOVE TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/do(/*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] 

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/do(/*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```